# Uploading a MSI to a Visual Studio Private Gallery

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, windows-installer, vsix

Recently I have been trying to create a Private Gallery for Visual Studio Extensions. The big problem being the lack of documentation available from Microsoft.

The [Main Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh266746.aspx) describes the "easy" part of adding them to Visual Studio once they are done, and redirects to two different pages, to create them via Atom (RSS) Feed or with SharePoint.

Atom seems to be the better option right now, and I have managed to put it visible for Visual Studio, however, the only example given by Microsoft:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
- <feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
  <title type="text" /> 
  <id>uuid:bcecded5-97c8-4d24-96f1-7d9e16652433;id=1</id> 
  <updated>2011-04-14T21:25:48Z</updated> 
- <entry>
  <id>SelectionHighlight..a14874d2-8199-4a60-af8a-11d6447813aa</id> 
  <title type="text">Highlight all occurrences of selected word</title> 
  <summary type="text">This extends the editor to highlight ….</summary> 
  <published>2011-04-14T14:24:51-07:00</published> 
  <updated>2011-04-14T14:24:22-07:00</updated> 
- <author>
  <name>Microsoft</name> 
  </author>
  <link rel="icon" href="VSIXImages/SelectionHighlight..a14874d2-8199-4a60-af8a-11d6447813aa_Icon_SelectionHighlightIcon.jpg" /> 
  <link rel="previewimage" href="VSIXImages/SelectionHighlight..a14874d2-8199-4a60-af8a-11d6447813aa_PreviewImage_SelectionHighlight.jpg" /> 
  <content type="application/octet-stream" src="SelectionHighlight.vsix" /> 
- <Vsix xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vsx-syndication-schema/2010">
  <Id>SelectionHighlight..a14874d2-8199-4a60-af8a-11d6447813aa</Id> 
  <Version>1.31</Version> 
  <References /> 
  <Rating xsi:nil="true" /> 
  <RatingCount xsi:nil="true" /> 
  <DownloadCount xsi:nil="true" /> 
  </Vsix>
  </entry>
- <entry>
  <id>Template_Wizard_239.Microsoft.3b38a7e3-5cbc-4389-a92a-d82tyc2ed592</id> 
  …
  </entry>
  </feed>
```

Specifies how to add a VSIX, and thanks to [this website](http://blogs.msmvps.com/p3net/2013/01/11/hosting-a-private-visual-studio-gallery/) I could understand the order and meaning of some fields, but it also says this for MSI Extensions: "It is generally assumed that an extension is shipped as a VSIX but it could also be an MSI. Beyond the source URL not much changes in the gallery." However, it doesn't seem to work as I tried.

Right now, with the MSI, Visual Studio downloads it and then says it is "not a valid VSIX Package". My goal is to make them like the Microsoft's Visual Studio Extensions and other Third Party extensions that install via MSI, that take you to an URL that makes you download the MSI, but I can manage to do that.

Also considered to "disguise" the MSI inside the VSIX, but VSIX doesn't support MSIs inside it.

Any ideas on how to prepare the RSS for MSI extensions?

Thanks in advance.